# How can I get material property data past what's provided via ElementData[], ChemicalData[], etc.?

Tags: curated-data, chemistry, entity

## Background

Let's say I want information (e.g. bulk modulus or space group) on an element or chemical compound that isn't available via e.g. `ElementData[]`, `LatticeData[]`, or `ChemicalData[]`.

### Examples

```
ChemicalData["FeO2"]
```

> ChemicalData::notent: "FeO2" is not a known entity, class, or tag for ChemicalData. Use ChemicalData[] for a list of entities.

```
ChemicalData["Fe3C"]
```

> ```
> Missing["NotAvailable"]
> ```

## Question

How can I go about programmatically obtaining this information? API suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

## Materials Project

[The Materials Project](https://materialsproject.org/) contains an extensive amount of materials property data and has [an API](https://materialsproject.org/open) which can be accessed in Mathematica via a [RESTful API workflow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/GetDataFromARESTfulAPI.html).

See the [MaterialProperties](https://github.com/sgbaird/Mathematica/tree/master/MaterialProperties) package on my GitHub page for an implementation of this.

## Example Usage

### Space Group Properties of Iron Carbide

```
MaterialProperties["Fe3C", "spacegroup"]
```

> <|"symprec" -> 0.1, "source" -> "spglib", "symbol" -> "Pnma",
> "number" -> 62, "point_group" -> "mmm",
> "crystal_system" -> "orthorhombic", "hall" -> "-P 2ac 2n"|>

### Space Group Number of Iron Carbide

```
MaterialProperties["Fe3C", "spacegroup", "number"]
```

> ```
> 62
> ```

### K Voigt

See [Elasticity Calculations](https://wiki.materialsproject.org/Elasticity_calculations) for some properties and units

```
MaterialProperties["Fe3C", "elasticity", "K_Voigt"] (*GPa*)
```

> ```
> 224.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `ChemicalData[]` that still uses the Mathematica built-in database.

```
element=Entity["Chemical","IronCarbide"];
entityProperties=EntityValue[element,"Properties"];
entityValues=EntityValue[element,entityProperties];
Select[entityValues,!MissingQ[#]&];
propertyValues=Select[{entityProperties,entityValues}\[Transpose],!MissingQ[#[[2]]]&];
propertyValues//TableForm
```

[image]

Unfortunately, you may still not find the properties you're looking for using this way, so you can use the API package as above.

Answer (score 2):

You can get partial results using the [`WolframAlpha`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) function. Either

```
WolframAlpha["iron carbide"]
```

or

```
WolframAlpha["chemical compound Fe3C"]
```

produce
[image]